# Post 8088 is open and is pointed to url but still getting a "The requested resource is not available

Tags: server

I am working remotely on a ubuntu 18.04 server through PuTTY. I have a docker container running on port 8088 [Port Listen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W2FM.png)

I have the localhost:8088 pointed to xyz.abc.de.

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled and /etc/apache2/sites-available both have a virtual host pointing to this URL. I also added the domain name in /etc/hosts

I am still getting a 404:The requested resource is not available error

Comment: and when you run `curl -v localhost:8088` from the server it works well ? And what about `curl -v xyz.abc.de:8088` ?

Comment: yes it works on this port. I get the tomcat homepage and the connection to the URL:8088 is working with these commands. But I still get the 404:resource not available error on the browser. Maybe the service I am trying to run is not configured correctly

Answer (score 1):

Add xyz.abc.de to your hosts.

Edit /etc/hosts file with:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Change line:

127.0.0.1       localhost

with:

127.0.0.1       localhost xyz.abc.de

Comment: Thanks. I updated the hosts file, still getting the error. Maybe the docker container and the service running in it needs to be rebuild